# path.join() yeilds duplicate or none

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a pretty weird situation here.

**1.**
When I use this code in my `tokens.js` file

```
const pathToPrivKey = path.join(__dirname, "..", "src/helpers/key/id_rsa_priv.pem");
```

The error is:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\arpitanand\Desktop\node-app\src\src\helpers\key\id_rsa_priv.pem'
```

Notice that `src` is automatically duplicated in the path string as `\src\src\`

**2.** When I use this code in my `tokens.js` file:

```
const pathToPrivKey = path.join(__dirname, "..", "helpers/key/id_rsa_priv.pem");
```

The error is:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\arpitanand\Desktop\node-app\helpers\key\id_rsa_pub.pem'
```

Notice here that now both the `/src/src/` is absent!

**This is my folder structure:**

```
----src
|   |
|   +---controller
|   |
|   +---helpers
|   |   |   tokens.js  //I am here
|   |   +---key
|   |           id_rsa_priv.pem //I want to access this file
|   |           id_rsa_pub.pem
+---test
        deleteUser.js
```

**UPDATE**

**1.**
The output `console.log(_dirname)` is:

```
C:\Users\arpitanand\Desktop\node-app\src\helpers
```

**2.** And I have already ran this

```
const pathToPrivKey = path.join(__dirname, "key/id_rsa_priv.pem");
```

The result of which is:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\arpitanand\Desktop\node-app\helpers\key\id_rsa_priv.pem'
```

**3.** I use the `pathToPrivKey` here and only here:

```
const PRIV_KEY = fs.readFileSync(pathToPrivKey, "utf8");
```

Comment: Please show us the output of `console.log( __dirname )`  in each situation - otherwise I'll downvote you for failing to do basic debugging.

Comment: Also, your **desktop folder** is probably not the best place to put your development projects...

Comment: I have added please check the updated question :)

Comment: Also, there's no way `path.join()` would throw an `ENOENT` exception. You're not showing the code that would try to access the file.

Comment: What other portions of the code should I show? As I think the work is only being done by  this particular line of code

Comment: Surely you use `keyPath` somewhere to access the file?

Comment: Ok, so I have updated the question again. Please refresh :)

Comment: You're still not telling us everything. You claim to have `pathToPrivKey` with `id_rsa_priv.pem`, yet you claim to get an exception referring to `id_rsa_pub.pem`. That's entirely impossible, don't you think?

Comment: Ok, so I did a little mistake there copying the error created by the other part of the code in which I use the public key. Since I have two keys and I am using both the keys with identical lines of code and the same error is occurring for both. Therefore for the sake of simplicity I had shown only one of those i.e, the one with the private key. I have omitted that error. Sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

[`__dirname` is the directory in which the module resides](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname), not e.g. the working directory of the program.

If you have code in `src/helpers/tokens.js` and want to refer to `src/helpers/key/id_rsa_priv.pem`,

```
const keyPath = path.join(__dirname, "key/id_rsa_priv.pem");
```

is enough.

Comment: I did already run the code you wrote, please check the updated question :)

Comment: Well, are you sure that file exists?

Comment: Yes absolutely!

Comment: Really, absolutely, super duper sure? You can do `type C:\Users\arpitanand\Desktop\node-app\helpers\key\id_rsa_pub.pem` in your command prompt and it prints out stuff?

Comment: Also, as I said in the other comment, `path.join()` does not throw exceptions. It doesn't care whether the file exists or doesn't. You have some other code that tries to access the file.

Comment: Yes, I have checked this many times, I am accessing the right file in CMD

Comment: And also I am using the code to reach the file only in one place in my project

Comment: @ArpitAnand `cmd` does not have the _exact same_ "filesystem experience" (for want of a better phrase) as a NodeJS program does - just because it works in `cmd.exe` does not mean it works in your code.

Comment: @Dai So what do you propose?

Comment: @ArpitAnand **USE YOUR DEBUGGER YOU PHILISTINE** and step-through your code and inspect the variables to see where your program's logic is going wrong. You have provided insufficient detail for us to diagnose your problem and unfortunately for you we don't have psychic telepathic powers to magically know what's going wrong from afar given the _very limited_ information you've given us so far.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words @Dai. But my code is working now :)

Comment: @ArpitAnand I am chock-full of kind words :) 

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I don't really know what was happening with my code before but I tried cleaning the **npm cache** using `npm cache clean --force` along with deleting my `node modules` and reinstalling them and it worked!

Comment: I don't think npm or node_modules had anything to do with your problem :)